# Suma de objectos en un array con "llaves" distintas javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

tengo un array como este:

```
let arr = [
 "01/01/2020":["{cantidad":10,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":15,"codigo":102}],
 "02/01/2020":["{cantidad":15,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":12,"codigo":102}],
 "03/01/2020":["{cantidad":12,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":20,"codigo":102}],
 "04/01/2020":["{cantidad":18,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":26,"codigo":102}],
]
```

Lo que espero hacer es sumar los valores de cada fecha en un nuevo array pero que mantenga las mismas keys en los objetos.

```
arr2=[
    0:{"cantidad":55,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":73,"codigo":102}
   ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por aqui te dejo como lo solucionaria yo:

```js
    function castProducts(arr) {
      const result = [];

      arr.forEach(otherArray => {
        otherArray.forEach(prod => {
          const index = result.findIndex(desc => desc.codigo == prod.codigo);
          if (index >= 0) {
            result[index].cantidad += prod.cantidad;
          } else {
            result.push(prod);
          }
        });
      })

      return result;
    }
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda!